# JPA Hibernate fetchSize Query hint Issue

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have been using JPA 2.0 with hibernate as the vendor for my web application.  For one of the database queries, I am using the JPA criteria builder API to construct the dynamic queries . I have been able to get it to work as expected.

The query has a fetch join between two tables A & B. A has a OneToMany relationship with B.

```
Join<A,B> ordLeg = ord.joinSet("bLegs", JoinType.INNER);
ord.fetch("bLegs",JoinType.INNER);
```

I also have used the setMaxResults to restrict the no. of records returned to the user

```
typedQuery.setMaxResults(10);
```

FYI, there are around 400 records in the database.

When I see the result of the query in the logs, I see that it loads all the 400 records in the memory. However, it returns only 20 records to the user since Maxresults is set.

When analyzed further, found out that hibernate has hints that can be given to fetch records in batches rather than loading all the 400 records in the memory.

```
TypedQuery<A> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
typedQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.fetchSize", 5);
List<A> orderList = (List<A>) typedQuery.getResultList();
```

But it does not seem to take the hint at all. I am still seeing that it loads all 400 records in the memory and no batch fetching is done. I am expecting it to fetch the 10 (maxResults ) records in 2 batches of 5.  Am i missing something ?\

It will be a severe performance hit if there are more than 1000 records in the DB  for the specified query.

I even tried setting the following property in the persistence.xml level but in vain.

```
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="5"/>  
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="5">
</properties>
```

Can you please help me out in the right direction ?

Hibernate Version:  I have tried 3.6.4.Final, 4.0.0.Final &  4.2.1.Final

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maxresults might not work as expected due to joins. suppose each user has 10 addresses and you expect 10 users, so db query should give you 10x10=100 records, then jpa has to put user in one object with list of 10 addresses as collection. so you will see discrepancies in result set and final objects returned.
fetch size will tell jpa to fetch those many records only through jdbc call. the smaller the fetch size, more the no of calls jpa makes to db going back n forth.
try to increase your fetch size if query is not very heavy, in your case of 400 records, with one inner join, you can easily play with higher value of fetch size.

Comment: Thanks Ashish.. But maxResults works as expected. meaning, I get as many records as I put in my setMaxResults. But the fetchSize query hint has no effect. I changed the fetchSize to 100 and max results as 200 to see whether it fetches in batches of 2. I am able to see 200 records(setMaxresults) in the response but it loads all 400 records in the memory. Setting the fetch size as part of the TypedQuery has no effect.